# What other lightning nodes are there besides Eclair Core for running a full node lightning?

Tags: lightning-network, full-node, eclair

I realized that in order to receive lightning payments from others, you need to first run a lightning full node. I found this one from Eclair: https://github.com/ACINQ/eclair

Are there other full node lightning implementations like Eclair node that are just as reliable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few lightning network full node implementations, that follow the [LN specifications.](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc) Note that in many ways the specs, and software, are considered experimental, and should be used at your own risk.

- [C-lightning is written in C](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning)
- [LND is written in Golang](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd)